# Using 2D Array for BFS

Tags: c, algorithm, path-finding

I have a grid that I keep cells with values 1 and 0 (they are generated randomly). A cell with value 1 means it's an empty cell an I can move to that cell and with 0 it means that this cell is blocked. I want to be able for every position (x,y) to tell if there is an available path to a point (x',y') by moving to all 4 directions but not diagonally.

From a research a solution to my problem is BFS algorithm but I struggle to understand how we transform that array to a graph and how we keep the information of the blocked cells.

Comment: This is what a [Grid graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_graph) looks like

Comment: You don't "transform that array to a graph" at all. You implement a process of grid cell traversal that can be thought of as a tree. (From the starting node, you have a number of choices; and from every choice, you have further choices, and so on.) BFS means that you start with all possible paths of length 1; then all those of length 2; of length 3... At every stage, you keep a list of the paths of length L and from these determine the paths of length L+1.

Answer (score 0):

The general structure of a BFS is as follows:

1. Create a queue.
2. Enqueue the root node.
3. While the queue isn't empty,

   1. Dequeue a node.
   2. Visit the node.
   3. Enqueue the children of the node.

As applied here,

1. Create a queue.
2. Create `visited`, an array with a bit for each cell.
3. For each row `y`,

   1. For each col `x`,

      1. If cell (`x`,`y`) has a value of `1`,

         1. Set the `visited` bit for cell (`x`,`y`).
      2. Else,

         1. Clear the `visited` bit for cell (`x`,`y`).
4. Enqueue the point (x,y).
5. While the queue isn't empty,

   1. Dequeue a point (`x2`,`y2`).
   2. If the `visited` bit for cell (`x2`,`y2`) isn't set,

      1. Set the `visited` bit for cell (`x2`,`y2`).
      2. If the point (`x2`,`y2`) is equal to (x',y'),

         1. Return true.
      3. For each cell adjacent to cell (`x2`,`y2`),

         1. Enqueue the coordinates of that cell.
6. Return false.

(It doesn't have to be a bit array. It just has to provide fast lookups and inserts. One could use some form of associative array, for example. A bit vector seemed most apt to me.)

---

But that's not quite right. You don't want to simply check if two cells are connected, you want to know which cells is connected to which. It would be awfully slow to run the above search for every combination of cells. The following avoids repeating work:

1. Create a queue.
2. Create `groups`, an array with an integer for each cell.
   The integer must be large enough to hold the number of cells, plus 2.
   `VOID` refers the maximum value this integer can take.
   `TODO` refers the maximum value this integer can take, minus 1.
3. For each row `y`,

   1. For each col `x`,

      1. If cell (`x`,`y`) has a value of `1`,

         1. Set the integer for cell (`x`,`y`) in `groups` to `TODO`.
      2. Else,

         1. Set the integer for cell (`x`,`y`) in `groups` to `VOID`.
4. Set `group_id` to `0`.
5. For each row `y`,

   1. For each col `x`,

      1. If the group for cell (`x`,`y`) is `TODO`,

         1. Enqueue the point (`x`,`y`).

            1. While the queue isn't empty,

               1. Dequeue point (`x2`,`y2`)
               2. If the group for cell (`x2`,`y2`) is `TODO`,

                  1. Set the group for cell (`x2`,`y2`) to `group_id`.
                  2. For each cell adjacent to cell (`x2`,`y2`),

                     1. Enqueue the coordinates of that cell.
         2. Increment `group_id`.

Once this is executed, every cell is connected to every other cell with the same value in `groups`.

(Again, there's flexibility in the exact data structures used.)

---

What follows is an example implementation. Like the above, it's still not in C. The point is to explain an approach you could use, but the actual C implementation is left to the user.

Inputs:

```perl
use POSIX qw( ceil );

my $num_rows = ...;
my $num_cols = ...;

my $n = $y * $num_cols + $x;

my $cells = "\0" x ceil( $n / 8 );   # A string of `$n` bits.

# Initialize cells here.
for ( ... ) {
    my $y = ...;
    my $x = ...;
    vec( $cells, $y * $num_cols + $x, 1 ) = 1;  # Sets a bit.
}
```

Algorithm:

```perl
my $visited = ~.$cells;   # String bitwise negation.

my @groups;   # This is going to be an array of arrays.
for my $i ( 0 .. $n-1 ) {
   next if vec( $visited, $i, 1 );

   my $group = [ ];
   push @groups, $group;

   my @to_visit = $i;   # Our queue (or stack).
   while ( @to_visit ) {
      my $j = shift( @to_visit );   # Use `pop` for DFS.
      next if vec( $visited, $j, 1 );

      vec( $visited, $j, 1 ) = 1;
      push @$group, $j;

      my $y2 = int( $j / $num_cols );
      my $x2 =      $j % $num_cols;

      for my $dy ( ( $y2 == 0 ? () : -1 ), ( $y2 == $num_rows-1 ? () : +1 ) ) {
      for my $dx ( ( $x2 == 0 ? () : -1 ), ( $x2 == $num_cols-1 ? () : +1 ) ) {
         push @to_visit, ( $y2 + $dy ) * $cols + ( $x2 + $dx );
      }}
   }
}
```

Output:

```perl
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

print( Dumper( \@groups ) );
```

---

Finally, note that a DFS would work just as well as a BFS. An implementation using a DFS would be identical, except the queue would be replaced with a stack.

Comment: Thanks for your time,   i will try to implement the algorithm you told me . I did not understand though much by the perl implementation because i dont know anything about the perl syntax but still thank you for helping me.